# Silverlight to ASP.net MVC migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, migration

I am tasked with migrating a Silverlight application to ASP.net MVC5. The challenge is that some of the modules have already been built in an MVC app that can run stand-alone or can load from within the Silverlight application. The existing MVC application has been developed over last 2-3 years by several developers of varying skillsets and the code is not in very good shape. The code has very poor coding standards adherence and poor re-usability, no coded unit tests, no DI, lots of inline styling, etc.

I want to start afresh with a new MVC project for the Silverlight migration so that I can try and address the issues in the current MVC app. Eventually, I want to reach a point where the Silverlight and the old MVC apps can be completely discarded and the new MVC app becomes the only one running. However, until the migration is complete, all three need to coexist. With the Silverlight application, I do not foresee a problem as I can tweak it to load the MVC pages from two different MVC sites. However, the main challenge I am facing is in figuring out a strategy so that users can access the new modules from the new MVC app from the old app until I migrate the old modules to the new app. It would not be feasible to make users access two different web apps for different features.

Some of the possibilities I have explored are,

1. hosting the new application separately but loading the pages into iframes from the old MVC site.
2. using something like Razor Generator to precompile the new project and refer it from the old application.

I am not very sure if the above are the best of ideas. I would greatly appreciate any suggestion to help me think and proceed in the right direction. Would also love to hear if there is a better/more appropriate approach to solve this problem.

Comment: How about hosting them separately (ie. old mvc and silverlight web application are separate from the new one mvc5, ofc both are still in the same domain) and letting the users choose which version to access. This way, you don't need to tweak the old stuff and concentrate on the new one instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Bahamut. Are you suggesting that the user has to be aware that a certain module is available in one app while another module is in some other app and access accordingly? Should this not be transparent to the user?

Comment: Sorry, I might have misunderstood but I thought you will be kind of porting the old project to MVC5 which would have exactly the same modules plus new the modules. Do you mean the new modules will be/needs to be developed first before starting the MVC5 app?

Comment: As I said earlier, the old MVC project has lots of design flaws and bad coding which makes it very difficult to maintain as well as test. Refactoring the old app is not an option given the time constraint. That is the reason I was looking at some way to start the Silverlight migration on a clean slate but still having some way to let the user access the newly developed modules through the old MVC app so that nothing changes for them.

Comment: I think it's ok to let them know that there will be a new website to replace the old one and the reason for doing so even if it's a simple explanation like it will be better and more standard compliant but still contains the previous available modules plus the new ones. Build the new app and make the old modules available first then make the new modules and then discard the old application.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Looks like that would be the feasible option at this point. I was trying to leave the existing MVC modules untouched until after the SL modules migration but probably that will not work out.